# A `\coordinate` command ignored

Tags: tikz-pgf

$\triangle[ABC]$ is a 30-60 right triangle, and its right angle is at `C`. `A` is at the origin. A circle is inscribed in it; its center is at

```
O = (2*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3) - 1), 2*(sqrt(3) - 1))
```

and its radius is `12(sqrt(3) - 1)`. Leg `AC` is the shorter leg. The equation of the line through it is `y = sqrt(3)*x`. The line perpendicular to `AC` has slope `-sqrt(3)/3`, and the line through `O` with slope `-sqrt(3)/3` is

```
y = (-sqrt(3)/3)*(x - 2*(sqrt(3))*(sqrt(3)-1)) + 2*(sqrt(3)-1) .
```

The two lines intersect on leg `AC` at

```
Q = (8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1), 24*(sqrt(3)-1)) .
```

So, the command `\draw (O) -- (Q);` should draw a radius of the circle to leg `AC`. On my computer, the command renders a line segment through the other leg and ridiculously long. It seems to me that the command locating point `Q` has been ignored.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (8,0) coordinate (B) (2,{2*sqrt(3)}) coordinate (C);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (0,-0.15){\textit{A}};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){\textit{C}};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path let \n1={2*(sqrt(3))*(sqrt(3)-1)}, \n2={2*(sqrt(3)-1)} in coordinate (O) at (\n1,\n2);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[blue] let \n1={2*(sqrt(3)-1)} in (O) circle (\n1);


\path let \n1={2*(sqrt(3))*(sqrt(3)-1)} in coordinate (P) at (\n1,0);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P) +(0,-0.15)$){\textit{P}};
\draw (O) -- (P);
\path let \n1={8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)}, \n2={24*(sqrt(3)-1)} in coordinate (Q) at (\n1,\n2);
\draw[fill=green] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[green] (O) -- (Q);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot Why didn't I have to include `*1pt` in the commands locating `O` and `P`?

Comment: This was just a guess, and it was wrong. However, you ask Ti*k*Z to do `\path let \n1={8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)}, \n2={8*3*(sqrt(3)-1)} in coordinate (Q) at (\n1,\n2);` which is equivalent to `\path ({8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)},{8*3*(sqrt(3)-1)}) coordinate (Q);` (meaning you do not need `calc` for that, and this is where Ti*k*Z places the point.

Comment: I want to manually locate `Q`. You may not believe that the coordinates I give render `OQ` perpendicular to leg `AC`, but you should know that it will be a point on leg `AC`.

Comment: `TikZ` is not putting `Q` on leg `AC`, though.

Comment: I added more explanations why that is. Please consider the possibility that it is not Ti*k*Z' fault.

Comment: I edited my code to make it clearer. The point `Q` should be on leg `AC`. `TikZ` is not plotting it on leg `AC`, though.

Comment: It is, just add `\draw[red,dashed] (A) -- (Q);` to your code. This produces a dashed line that runs from A through C to Q. The problem is that you made a mistake when solving for the coefficients.

Comment: Yep. The point `Q` is on the line through `A` and `C`.

Comment: I multiplied both coordinates of `Q` by `8` errantly.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, I cannot follow your equations at all. you ask TikZ to do

```
 \path let \n1={8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)}, \n2={8*3*(sqrt(3)-1)} in coordinate (Q) at (\n1,\n2);
```

which is equivalent to

```
 \path ({8*sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)},{8*3*(sqrt(3)-1)}) coordinate (Q);
```

(meaning you do not need calc for that), and this is where TikZ places the point. I cannot tell you everything that went wrong in your computation of `Q`, but here is one point: how is it possible that you do not need the coordinates of `O` in your way of doing things? You should be solving

```
 alpha * 1 = O_x + beta
 alpha * sqrt(3) = O_y - beta * sqrt(3)/3
```

if you want to find the point where `AC` intersects with the line that is perpendicular and runs through `O`, but I cannot see you doing this. (BTW, there is `intersection cs:` specifically for that, you do not need to do such things by hand.)

Luckily these projections can be done with `calc` out of the box.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$\scriptstyle A$] (A) --
({8*1},0) coordinate[label=below:$\scriptstyle B$] (B) --
({8*(1/4)},{8*sqrt(3)/4}) coordinate[label=above:$\scriptstyle A$] (C) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] ({8*(sqrt(3)/4)*(sqrt(3)-1)},{8*(1/4)*(sqrt(3)-1)}) 
 coordinate (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[blue]  (O) circle({8*(sqrt(3)-1)/4});

\path ($(A)!(O)!(C)$) coordinate[label=left:$\scriptstyle Q$] (Q)
 ($(A)!(O)!(B)$) coordinate[label=below:$\scriptstyle P$] (P);
\draw (O) -- (P);
\draw[fill=green] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[green] (O) -- (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you agree that the coordinate that I give for `Q` are the coordinates for a point on the line `y = sqrt(3)*x`?

Comment: `A` and `C` are points on the line. The y-coordinate is `sqrt(3)` times bigger than the x-coordinate for these points. Same is true for `Q`. Why does `TikZ` not plot Q on `AC`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire How is that important? This answer provides a way to do the projection independently of these computations and irrespective of whether or not you set the origin at `A`. If your comment is to ask whether the fact that in your Q does not appear where you want it to be due to an error in Ti*k*Z or in your code, my bet is that it is not Ti*k*Z. As I said, I could not follow your logic.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the circumscribed circle: Draw the perpendicular bisectors of AB and AC; their intersection is the center O of the circle.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\fangle{60}
\def\sangle{30}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,{2*tan(\fangle)});
\path [draw,name path=AB](A)node[left]{$A$}--(B);
\path [draw,name path=BC](B)node[right]{$B$}--(C);
\path [draw,name path=CA](C)node[above]{$C$}--(A);
\path [name path=A-bisector] (A)--++(\fangle/2:8);
\path [name path=B-bisector] (B)--++(180-\sangle/2:8);
\path [name intersections={of=A-bisector and B-bisector, by={O}}];
\path [name path=radius] (O)--++(-90:8);
\path [name intersections={of=AB and radius, by={P}}];
\node [draw,name path=circle,blue] at (O) [circle through={(P)}] {};
\path [name intersections={of=circle and CA, by={Q}}];
\filldraw (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O)--(P)node[below]{$P$};
\draw[green] (O)--(Q)node[left,color=black]{$Q$};
\filldraw (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]