# Making a right-angle mark using the `calc` package in `TikZ`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a right triangle and the altitude from the vertex of its right angle drawn. `A=(-4,0)`, `B=(0,3)`, and `C=(0,0)` are the vertices of the triangle, and `F=(-36/25,48/25)` is the foot of the altitude on the hypotenuse `AB`. I use the following commands to draw a right-angle mark.

```
\coordinate (U) at ($(F)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(F)$) -- (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(F)$);
```

Why doesn't it look like three sides of a square with edge length `3mm`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (circle_1) at (-8/5, 4/5);
\draw[blue, fill=blue=25!] (circle_1) circle (4/5);

\coordinate (circle_1) at (-3/5, 9/5);
\draw[orange, fill=orange=25!] (circle_1) circle (3/5);


\path (-4,0) coordinate (A) (0,3) coordinate (B) (0,0) coordinate (C);
\coordinate (F) at (-36/25,48/25);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (F) -- (C);



%A right-angle mark is drawn at F.
\coordinate (U) at ($(F)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(F)$) -- (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(F)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!3mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) -- (U) -- ($(B)!(U)!(C)$);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice figure! I may use it to accompany a problem on a test in Geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem related to the inaccuracies of `\pgfpintnormalised`, as discussed in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256377/121799). Your problem is the very same as the one noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168120/121799). The issues do not arise when one draws things with arguably more direct methods.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (circle_1) at (-8/5, 4/5);
\draw[blue, fill=blue=25!] (circle_1) circle (4/5);

\coordinate (circle_1) at (-3/5, 9/5);
\draw[orange, fill=orange=25!] (circle_1) circle (3/5);


\path (-4,0) coordinate (A) (0,3) coordinate (B) (0,0) coordinate (C);
\coordinate (F) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (F) -- (C);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at F.
\draw ($(F)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!(A)$) coordinate (aux) -- 
($(aux)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!90:(A)$) -- ($(F)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!(C)$);
(C);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\draw ($(C)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!(A)$) coordinate (aux) -- 
($(aux)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!-90:(A)$) -- ($(C)!{sqrt(9/2)*1mm}!(B)$);
(C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I used `3cm` instead of `3mm`, three sides of a square were drawn.

Comment: Fine. I will manually encode the coordinates of the vertices for the square.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Seems we have a problem communicating. I do not know what you mean by your first comment, and I also do not know why you do not think that [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485816/121799) does not deserve to be accepted. All I can say is that the above code does not seem to suffer from the inaccuracies, nor does it contain `3mm` anywhere such that I can appreciate what you mean by  "When I used `3cm` instead of `3mm`,...".

Comment: I just accepted it. Yes, that does give a box - right-angle mark - with diagonals of length `3mm.`

Comment: Why does `TikZ` render this code correctly but not the code in my post? Both use the `calc` package.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, I am saying that if you replace `3mm` with `3cm` in the command `\coordinate (U) at ($(F)!3mm!45:(A)$);`, you will get a square. Why does the `calc` package work for `3cm` and not for `3mm`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire This is all because of the internal use of `\pgfpointnormalised` in `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex`. Both ways use it but if you do the projections the inaccuracies get amplified by the fact that you subtract something that is proportional to the scalar product with the outcome of `\pgfpointnormalised`. The perhaps cleanest way would be to use [Mark Wibrow's fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256377/121799). This also explains the discrepancy between `3mm` and `3cm`, simply the inaccuracy gets amplified less.